# Regexp matching of list of quotes strings - unquoted

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

in Javascript, the following:

```
var test = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';
var result = test.match(/".*?"/g);
alert(result);
```

yields "the quick","brown fox","jumps over","the lazy dog"

I want each matched element to be unquoted: the quick,brown fox,jumps over,the lazy dog

what regexp will do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var test = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';
var result = test.match(/[^"]+(?=(" ")|"$)/g);
alert(result);
```

Note: This doesn't match empty elements (i.e. ""). Also, it won't work in browsers that don't support JavaScript 1.5 (lookaheads are a 1.5 feature).

See http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml for more info.

Answer (score 4):

It is not one regexp, but two simpler regexps.

```
var test = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';

var result = test.match(/".*?"/g);
// ["the quick","brown fox","jumps over","the lazy dog"]

result.map(function(el) { return el.replace(/^"|"$/g, ""); });
// [the quick,brown fox,jumps over,the lazy dog]
```

Comment: Yeah i can see how this would work, but I sorta figure if I am going to plant some ugly-ass regexp stuff in my code, it oughta be worth it by do everything i want in one shot. :)

Answer (score 1):

grapefrukt's answer works also. I would up using a variation of David's

```
match(/[^"]+(?=("\s*")|"$)/g)
```

as it properly deals with arbitrary amounts of white space and tabs tween the strings, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Javascript replace() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to strip them out.

```
var test = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';

var result = test.replace(/"/, '');
```

Is there more to it than just getting rid of the double-quotes?

Comment: i specifically want the result array that match() returns.  i know i can trim each element, but i'm sure there's a way to do it one-step using a crafty regular expression

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use in actionscript3:

```
var test:String = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';
var result:Array = test.match(/(?<=^"| ").*?(?=" |"$)/g);
for each(var str:String in result){
    trace(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For matching content between pairs of simple quotes and double quotes taking care of escaped ones.

As search engine first drove me here, I really would like to orient people looking to check quotes pairs to the more generic question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867753/2012407.

The regex will get the full content between well formed pairs of quotes like `'"What\'s up?"'` for instance that are not in a code comment like `// Comment.` or `/* Comment. */`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way:

```
var test = '"the quick" "brown fox" "jumps over" "the lazy dog"';
var result = test.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, "$1");
alert(result);
```

Comment: thanks but result is simply a string. i want a 4-element array ( what match() returns ) with the quotes stripped away

Comment: Ah, sry.  My javascript's a bit rusty.  Looks like there are no regex lookbehinds in javascript.  So David's answer is your best bet.