# Comprehensive RegExp to remove JavaScript comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to dependably remove all JavaScript comments with a single Regular Expression.

I have searched StackOverflow, and other sites, but none take into account alternating quotes, multi-line comments, comments within strings, regular expressions, etc.

Is there any Regular expressions that can remove the comments from this:

```js
var test = [
    "// Code",
    '// Code',
    "'// Code",
    '"// Code',
    //" Comment",
    //' Comment',
    /* Comment */
    // Comment /* Comment
    /* Comment
     Comment // */ "Code",
    "Code",
    "/* Code */",
    "/* Code",
    "Code */",
    '/* Code */',
    '/* Code',
    'Code */',
    /* Comment
    "Comment",
    Comment */ "Code",
    /Code\/*/,
    "Code */"
]
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://goo.gl/C9sjiS) or [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/k2ofVO) to test it.

Comment: Do you? Why? What's the context of this requirement? Have you made an attempt?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at creating the said regular expression? If so, post it here. But note, however, that this task may not be easy to achieve with just regular expressions. The best course of action is to use a real JavaScript parser.

Comment: Best regexp I've managed to find so far: /(?:\/\*(?:[\s\S]*?)\*\/)|(?:([\s;])+\/\/(?:.*)$)/gm

Comment: +1 for the high-quality fiddle

Comment: ... but `/Comment/gm` works :P

Comment: Have a look at  https://github.com/benjamn/recast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like challenges :)

Here's my working solution:

```
/((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/)|\/\/.*?$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//gm
```

Replace that with `$1`.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/DtGq8/6/

Of course, as it has been pointed out countless times, a proper parser would probably be better, but still...

NB: I used a regex literal in the fiddle insted of a regex string, too much escaping can destroy your brain.

---

## Breakdown

```
((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/) <-- the part to keep
|\/\/.*?$                                                         <-- line comments
|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/                                                 <-- inline comments
```

### The part to keep

```
(["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2                   <-- strings
\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/     <-- regex literals
```

#### Strings

```
    ["']              match a quote and capture it
    (?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?  match escaped characters or unescpaed characters, don't capture
    \2                match the same type of quote as the one that opened the string
```

#### Regex literals

```
    \/                          match a forward slash
    (?![*\/])                   ... not followed by a * or / (that would start a comment)
    (?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?   match any sequence of escaped/unescaped text, or a regex character class
    \/                          ... until the closing slash
```

### The part to remove

```
|\/\/.*?$              <-- line comments
|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/      <-- inline comments
```

#### Line comments

```
    \/\/         match two forward slashes
    .*?$         then everything until the end of the line
```

#### Inline comments

```
    \/\*         match /*
    [\s\S]*?     then as few as possible of anything, see note below
    \*\/         match */
```

I had to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` because unfortunately JavaScript doesn't support the regex `s` modifier (singleline - this one allows `.` to match newlines as well)

This regex will work in the following corner cases:

- Regex patterns containing `/` in character classes: `/[/]/`
- Escaped newlines in string literals

---

## Final boss fight

And just for the *fun* of it... here's the *eye-bleeding* hardcore version:

```
/((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|(?:[^\w\s]|^)\s*\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/(?=[gmiy]{0,4}\s*(?![*\/])(?:\W|$)))|\/\/.*?$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//gm
```

This adds the following twisted edge case ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/DtGq8/7/), [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bX8jV7/2)):

```
Code = /* Comment */ /Code regex/g  ; // Comment
Code = Code / Code /* Comment */ /g  ; // Comment    
Code = /Code regex/g /* Comment */  ; // Comment
```

This is highly *heuristical* code, you probably shouldn't use it (even less so than the previous regex) and just let that edge case blow.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to provide a detailed breakdown, but for now, it means: match an escaped character, or an unescaped one, without capturing it.

Comment: No. `\.` simply matches a dot. Also, the escaped character could be a newline, and the non-escaped character must neither be a backslash nor a delimiter.

Comment: @Bergi Whoops, of course for the `\.`, thanks. But in JS `.` doesn't match a newline, and the `.` won't match a backslash because of the first alternative

Comment: Yes, it doesn't, but it *should*. And the lone `.` will only not match a backslash if there is no backtracking. Sorry for nitpicking :-)

Comment: @Bergi No, `.` should **not** match a newline _unless_ the `s` modifier is set. This modifier doesn't exist in JS (see the note at the bottom of the answer). The lone `.` is not a problem here.

Comment: Also, added the case for the `/[/]/` regex pattern, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I mean that string literals can contain newlines (if escaped), but your regex doesn't match them.

Comment: Argh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't know that. I'll update the regex. ;)

Comment: @Bergi I forgot to say: actually, thanks for your nitpicking :)

Comment: Wow, thanks @LucasTrzesniewski ! Also thanks for pointing out how mind numbing escaping can be :). Here's a more elegant fix for the readability: http://jsfiddle.net/alancnet/DtGq8/3/

Comment: @alancnet hehe, also, take a look at that last edit :P

Comment: Very nice! In fact, your latest expression also fixes a bug I encountered with the first.. Windows! The first didn't match \r\n, and didn't filter my file correctly. I fixed it with [\r|\n], but by the time I got back to tell you, you had this FINAL BOSS FIGHT! +1 for all the hard work.

Comment: @alancnet Yeah there was a problem I noticed while I was doing that final regex. I've updated the first one though (using `$` and the `m` modifier), you should use that one instead, even if it's less *powerful*.

Comment: What is the reason not to use RegExp? Especially the boss fight expression? Is it because it's not human readable (except for super geniuses like yourself)? or is it that it's poor performance?

Comment: @alancnet The reason I'm advising you not to use that final one is that because of the heuristics I've introduced in it, the regex may fail in subtle ways on syntax I did not anticipate. The first regex is simpler, therefore it's more likely to be correct, even if we know it blows in one very unlikely case. That should be acceptable. Performance is not a problem at all, this regex is more likey to be *faster* than a parser written in JS. Also, I'm not a genius lol, I've just written a lot of regexes in the past ;)

Comment: Pretty old, but since I stumbled upon it, `/// <reference path="..." />` would be removed by this.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I suggest doing this with a proper JavaScript parser instead. Checkout this previous Q&A: [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

For the input you've provided<sup>1</sup>, here is a solution that might work:

Match the pattern:

```
/("(?:[^\r\n\\"]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^\r\n\\']|\\.)*'|\/[^*\/]([^\\\/]|\\.)*\/[gm]*)|\/\/[^\r\n]*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g
```

Here's a break down of the pattern:

```
/
  (                                     # start match group 1
      "(?:[^\r\n\\"]|\\.)*"             #   match a double quoted string
    | '(?:[^\r\n\\']|\\.)*'             #   match a single quoted string
    | \/[^*\/]([^\\\/]|\\.)*\/[gm]*     #   match a regex literal
  )                                     # end match group 1
  | \/\/[^\r\n]*                        # match a single line break
  | \/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/                    # match a multi-line break
/g
```

and replace it with `$1` (match group 1). The trick here is that anything besides a comment is matched in group 1, which get replaced with itself again but comments get replaced with an empty string.

Here's a [regexr](http://regexr.com/39390) demo that shows the following replacement:

```
  var test = [
      "// Code",
      '// Code',
      "'// Code",
      '"// Code',




       "Code",
      "Code",
      "/* Code */",
      "/* Code",
      "Code */",
      '/* Code */',
      '/* Code',
      'Code */',
       "Code",
      /Code\/*/,
      "Code */"
  ]
```

<sup>1</sup> Again, a parser is the way to go since regex literals might be confused with the division operator. If you have an assignment like `var x = a / b / g;` in your source, the solution above will break!

Comment: You seem to be well aware of the problems with this - why even suggest a regular expression? This fails for so many cases.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, for the fun of it :)

Comment: Solid retort :) It does look fun, you might want to suggest esprima and escodegen for something saner you can use to remove comments with in a line.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I was reluctant to recommend specific JS parsers since I have no personal experience with any of them. But I can post a previous Q&A about JS parser.

Comment: Why are single-quoted strings allowed to contain linebreaks but double-quoted ones are not? (btw, the `.` does not match an escaped linebreak). Also, `/[/]/` is a valid regular expression.

Comment: @Bergi, forgot to include `\r\n`. Luckily `/[/]/` wasn't in the OP's test set! All jokes aside, I think my example with the division operator should scare away any sane mind from going the regex way here (besides the eye-bleeding regex "solution"...).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at parsing JavaScript using a JavaScript parser of itself and then leverage the parser API to strip out what you don't want.  I have not personally done this, but regular expressions should be limited to regular content, which I doubt JS falls into.

Here are some good places to look.

[JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure comments in strings _are_ a regular language since they can't nest.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Regular expressions that can remove the comments

No. You cannot build a regex that will match a comment (so that you simply can replace the match with the empty string), because without lookbehind it is impossible to determine whether `//"` is a comment or the end of a string literal.

You could use a regex as a tokenizer (you "only" need to take care of string literals, regex literals, and the two types of comments), but I'd recommend to use a full-blown JavaScript parser, they are freely available.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the first "no", I'm pretty sure it's possible to determine whether `//"` is a comment or the end of a string literal depending on where in the regular expression you are. Moreover - intuitively since you only have a finite amount of stuff to save - this should be regular - I can certainly imagine a DFA for this. Your second paragraph is spot on though.

Comment: I mean a regular expression that **only** matches the comment - that seems to be impossible. Sure, with capturing groups and an intelligent replacer function that sorts out comments but keeps literals (similar to what BartKiers has done), it could be done.

Answer (score -1):

test.replace(/(/*([\s\S]*?)*/)|(//(.*)$)/gm, '');

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL