# Javascript singleline comments removed with bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

Have tried to get this to work for a while now without any success. I know there are similar posts about this topic but their examples doesn't work or their regexp's are to violent for my purpouse.
This is to heavy:
[Comprehensive RegExp to remove JavaScript comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518020/comprehensive-regexp-to-remove-javascript-comments)

My issue is quite simple, i have a unified javascript file created with a deploy.sh script and would like to have every line removed where the first characters occuring are "//" ignoring any preceding whitespaces and tabs like this:

```
// Remove this line
var foobar = "sometext";
    // remove this line with tab(s) before comment
    function foobar(); // Do not remove this!
  // remove this line with whitespace(s) before comment
```

This should be achived with a linux/ubuntu native tool or program language executed inside a shellscript without any external files useing something like sed.

I think having a convention of just using theese conditions for comment lines as removable should be quite straightforward with a minimal risk of misinterpreting. If i then like to have some comments to show in the production version i can then use the multiline comment annotation /* Comment */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell `grep` to discard everything starting with zero or more space sequences followed by `//`:

```
$ grep -v "^\s*//" file
var foobar = "sometext";
    function foobar(); // Do not remove this!
```

Comment: This worked, had to set the output to a temporary file first like this: grep -v "^\s*//" unified.js > tmp && mv tmp unified.js

Comment: @Dominus well done! This is the best way to do it, since if `grep` fails, no `mv tmp unified.js` will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but maybe this helps somebody:

`sed 's#\/\/.*##' file`

Comment: Seems like life was quite simple 7 years ago :), would probably go with webpack today even with custom vanilla projects :D

Answer (score 0):

Piping it through 'grep -v' should work, i.e. something like this (untested):

```
grep -Ev '^[ \t]*//' file > newfile
```

Grep's `-v` flag inverts matches: it prints all lines that do not match a regex to standard output. The lines that *do* match (your comment lines) are ignored.

Comment: Only got this one to work with comments that had preceeding whitespaces.

Comment: Ah yes, that should be * not +. Edited.

Comment: Worked for lines beginning with "//"  and preceeding whitespaces but still not if there are preceeding tabs :/ seems like removing \t from the regex doesn't make any difference to the result.

Comment: Turns out I was thinking of `-P` not `-E`. It should work with `grep -Pv` - but @fedorqui's regex is better if you want *all* whitespace instead of just tabs and spaces (you probably do).