# Extracting comments from stript by RegEx

Tags: regex

I need to remove all comments from a stript. Comments always start from '//'. My RegEx `/\/\/.*/g` does it but it removes substring if it inside quotes and I want avoid that behavior. Is there an ability to use RegEx for removing comments which are located only outside of quotes?

Comment: So you are saying that it should **not** remove something like `"foo //bar"`?

Comment: I remember this homework from school. :)

Comment: Yes, if there is something like: str="foo//bar//string" it shouldn't remove it, only if slashes are either before or after string.

Comment: [This question may help.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4568410)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (but I don't think this will match `//foo "string"`)

```
(?!.*")\/\/.*
```

Comment: Unfortunately javascript doesn't support negative lookahead.